# c# Order Strings by Regular Expression In The Middle

Tags: c#, sql-order-by

I have an article listing program. Here is an example of structure:

```
id      text
--      -----
1       AÜSBFD, Prof. Dr. Hıfzı Veldet Velidedeoğlu'na Armağan Sayısı, C.20, S.4, y.1968, s.27-49.
2       AÜSBFD, C.21, S.2, y.1946, Prof. Dr. Türkan Rado'ya Armağan Sayısı, s.1238-1278.
3       AÜSBFD, C.22, S.2, y.1974, s1-49.
4       AÜSBFD, C.22, Prof. Dr. Hüseyin Cahit Oğuzoğlu'na Armağan, S.3, y.1997, s.87-109.
5       AÜSBFD, C.23, S.1, y.2018, Prof. Dr. Aydın ZEVKLİLER'e Armağan, s.547-610.
```

For listing issues, I am using this:

```
private readonly LtoSQLiteDataContext _con = new LtoSQLiteDataContext();
var issues = _con.issues.OrderBy(x => x.id);

foreach (var i in issues)
{
    MessageBox.Show(i.text);
}
```

It returns like this:
[image]

But I want to sort these strings by the year which marked as yellow. But I have no idea.

Comment: can you please provide output of `OrderBy` in text format. It will be easier for testing

Comment: Are you sure year is stored in column "id"? It seems you're sorting on id which is another column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OrderBy`, you need to pass in a function that transforms your data model object into the year contained in the `Text` property.

Let's write such a method:

```
private static int GetYearFromText(YourModelType model) {
    var match = Regex.Match(model.Text, @"y\.(\d{4})");
    var numberString = match.Groups[1].Value;
    return Convert.ToInt32(numberString);
}
```

Note that the regex used is this:

```
y\.(\d{4})
```

The letter y followed by a dot followed by a capture group containing 4 digits.

And then you can pass that to `OrderBy`:

```
.OrderBy(GetYearFromText)
```

Note this will crash if the string does not match the regex, so make sure they all have a year.